# Table 'auth_user' already exits , when I try to migrate new tables to my local mysql database

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mysql-python

I am trying to deploy a Django project on my local machine.As far as I know, when I run migrate command, my_app tables along with django's table should be visible in my local database. When I run makemigration app_name command, I can see the correct SQL query is generated for my table. However, when I run migrate command, I get the error

> table 'auth_user' already exists

My database is empty before I run this. 
Also my migration folder has just the **init**.py file.

Following is the Error Log i get:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, impact_mapping, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying impact_mapping.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'auth_user' already exists")



The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 97, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 319, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 136, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\dpanch378\CBAT\component_mapping\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'auth_user' already exists")
(env)
```

Expected Outcome:I should get all the tables in my database
Actual Outcome: I get the error that auth_user table already exists.

Comment: Did you take a look in the databases created in mysql ? are they empty as expected ?

Comment: Yes. Before migrate cmd db is empty,

Comment: after migrate command and error , i only have django_migration table created @PRMoureu

Comment: @PRMoureu , did I answered your question?

Comment: yes it was a first silly but necessary check